# Assembly x86-64 idivq - floating point exception

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Trying to divide two intergers in assembly x86-64, getting `Floating point exception (core dumped)` and have traced it back to my idviq instruction.

```
xor %rdx, %rdx
movq %r11, %rdx // rdx now contains an integer
movq %r12, %rcx // rcx now contains an integer
idivq %rcx // floating point exception
```

I have also tried not using the rcx register and instead provided S directly through r12:

```
movq %r11, %rdx // rdx now contains an integer
idivq %r12 // floating point exception
```

Checking the registers with dbg shows that the integers I want to be in rdx (and rcx) is there. What's the problem here? I've been looking around on SO and found nothing usefull so far.

Comment: Which number are you trying to divide by which number? Show your algorithm in a higher-level language (like C), then translate to assembly. If it doesn't work, check the instruction set manual for the instructions you use. If you can't find the error, *then* provide your original algorithm and assembly code here, with an explanation why you think your assembly code corresponds to the algorithm.

Comment: I'm implementing the gcd euclidean algorithm, which requires modulu between an integer A and B, in this example A = 2684 and B = 732. I have done idivq in assembly before, but never encountered this problem.

Comment: Which register is the *denominator*, which is the *numerator*, what does your x86 instruction set reference have to say about this?

Comment: The numerator, according to my x86 instruction set reference is rdx, and the denominator is provided in the instruction, eg. idivq _register_.

Comment: Take another look at your instruction set reference, read the section on `idiv` *carefully*. If you still don't know the answer, what kind of broken instruction set reference are you using, use the official one from intel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idivq %rcx` will divide a 128-bit numerator, whose high half is in `%rdx` and whose low half is in `%rax`, by the 64-bit denominator in `%rcx`.  See [the description of `IDIV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv).

Your `%rdx` seems to contain your 64-bit numerator and you haven't initialized `%rax` at all.  So you are dividing some 128-bit garbage number by whatever's in `%rcx`.  If the result doesn't fit in 64 bits, you get a divide overflow exception, which Unix OSes typically handle by delivering SIGFPE, "Floating point exception", although no floating point is involved.  (There isn't a specific signal for integer divide overflow in Unix, and so they adopted this one as the closest fit.)

If your numerator is only 64 bits, load it into `%rax` and execute `cqto` (called [CQO](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) in Intel's naming) to sign-extend it into `%rdx`.  Then `idivq %rcx` will divide it by the 64-bit denominator in `%rcx`.  Note that overflow is only possible in this case if you divide the most negative signed 64-bit integer (`0x8000000000000000`) by `-1`, or if you divide by zero.

Comment: You were correct, my numerator was 64 bit. I loaded it into %rax and executed cqto, and then did the idivq instruction with the %rcx register. It worked perfectly. Thank you for the answer. Marked as solved.